# CodeIgniter - CSRF token cookie and Session ID Security

Tags: codeigniter, security, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter. I created an application using CI 3. When I click on Inspect Element, I can see that CSRF Token Cookie and Session ID is visible and anyone can steal it to login to the application.

So, how to prevent it? Please help.

To jusitfy my question, please check screenshot here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TbBd.png

Answer (score 0):

These are not just anyone's session and CSRF token cookies, they're *yours*, stored in your own browser. Nobody else can read them.